# Asterisk, RestAPI и получение информации о звонках

Tags: asterisk, rest

Приветствую всех!
Есть Asterisk версии 13. на нём включен RestAPI.
Я хочу с помощью этого RestAPI получать от ATC информацию о начале и конце звонка, 
и, желательно, о нажатиях клавиш на телефоне в процессе звонка.
Еще хоорошо бы получать звуковой поток. ("слушать звонок")
Но я попробовал - все мои попытки подключения к webSocket не заканчиваются ничем.
То есть, вебсокет сразу отключается.
Пользователь для RestAPI и его пароль созданы.

Может, я в принципе что то не так делаю?
Надо сделать какие то настройки на АТС?

Comment: Добрый день! Банально, но в /etc/asterisk/ari.conf параметр enabled = yes?

Comment: Да, конечно.  и pretty = yes тоже
вывод команды cli:
localhost*CLI> ari show status
ARI Status:
Enabled: Yes
Output format: pretty
Auth realm: Asterisk REST Interface
Allowed Origins: *
User count: 2
localhost*CLI>

Comment: В консоли asterisk в выводе команды `http show status` присутствует /ari/... => Asterisk RESTful API ? Уточню, вы подключаетесь к интерфейсу но не получаете данные. Или вообще не можете подключиться?

Comment: > Есть Asterisk версии 13. на нём включен RestAPI. Я хочу с помощью этого RestAPI получать от ATC информацию о начале и конце звонка, и, желательно, о нажатиях клавиш на телефоне в процессе звонка Для это есть AMI. Не пойму чем вам помог ARI, да еще и `/events`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Господа,
спасибо всем, кто прочитал и кто помогал мне разобраться. Отдельное спасибо Максиму Литницкому за его популярные статьи на русском. Но в результате мне помогли другие два человека, которые плохо знают Астериск, но обладают системным мышлением.

В результате всё получилось, и я просто должен поделиться этим с сообществом.

Астериск управляется специальным скриптом, который называется "dialplan".
Dialplan состоит из контекстов.
Этому нет прямой аналогии в мире программирования, но грубо говоря можно сравнить контекст с подпрограммой.
А весь Asterisk - с http-сервером, который обслуживает пользовательские сессии (звонки), переключаясь в процессе обслуживания с одной подпрограммы на другую.
Когда-то диалпланы писались руками, сейчас они все генерируются через WEB - интерфейс астериска.

Когда установлены нужные модули - см, например, инструкцию по по вот этой ссылке:
http://vinogradov.iptel.od.ua/rabota-s-asterisk-ari/ - можно начинать его мучить. Для начала надо попробовать мучить через обычный браузер.

Здесь помощником выступает swagger: http://ari.asterisk.org/. Естественно, там ничего не понятно, но в общем в верхней строчке надо написать ссылку на сервер, а там, где просят неведомый api key - Логин - пароль в формате "логин:пароль",
например:
`http://192.168.10.55:8089/ari/api-docs/resources.json`
и 
`konst:******`
(вместо звездочек подставьте свой пароль)

Этот веб-интерфейс дает общую картину того, какие объекты есть в астериске.
Но сделать с ними по прежнему ничего нельзя.
Для этого надо сделать еще два шага: перейти на веб-сокет и подписаться на события.

И тут всё дело в магических URL'ах.
В общем, если сделать соединение WEB-сокетом на URL вида:

```
"ws://192.168.10.55:8089/ari/events?app=qwer&subscribeAll=true&api_key=konst:******"
```

то произойдет маленькое чудо.
В этом URL в начале - адрес сервера и WS-порт (по умолчанию это порт 8088, я его поменял).
Потом - начало магического URL.
Потом `events?app=qwer` - это имя "несуществующего" астериск-приложения.

**И самое главное: `&subscribeAll=true`**

Именно эта строчка говорит астериску, что надо в этот сокет отправлять информацию о происходящих процессах!
Вот именно её мне и не хватало, когда я писал вопрос!
Без неё всё - вздор.

Ну а дальше - просто логин и пароль, шесть звездочек надо заменить на правильный пароль.
В результате если слушать WEB-сонтекст - то туда сваливается информация о переключении контекстов диалплана, 
то есть что то типа отладочной информации по обработке звонка.

Код создания веб-сокета на c#:

```
void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.10.55:8089/ari/events?app=qwer&subscribeAll=true&api_key=konst:******");

    ws.OnError += Ws_OnError;
    ws.OnOpen += Ws_OnOpen;
    ws.OnClose += Ws_OnClose;
    ws.OnMessage += Ws_OnMessage;
    ws.Connect();
}
```

В качестве WS-сокета я использовал [websocket-sharp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebSocketSharp)